# GWT Runtime vs Development mode

Tags: gwt, serialization

We are using GWT to develop a complex application . In development mode all the RPC's and the application work perfectly with reasonable performance.

But when we are in production mode some RPC calls are never been performed and the server side code never gets hit. We do a loadmask on some RPC calls and hid the loadmask on success.
But since the server code never got executed the loadmask is for ever and the application is in dead state.

Does anyone knows the reason behind the differences in dev and production mode? Also how do we track and debug on what's exactly happening in production mode apart from logging?
I kind of know that the problem is with the GWT serialization but how can know what the exact problem is so that i can modify my code.

Are there any tools that i could take advantage of?
I currently run my application in IE-8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways on how to debug these kind of problems:

1. For starters you could try to use [FireBug](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://getfirebug.com/&ei=B56FTpO3OI-whQex4vH-DA&usg=AFQjCNGT1rhhsYGPQx5Vr5A8RvhIgdSp9g) or any other developer tool to check the RPC payload and if actually a server request is fired in development mode.
2. You can tell the [compiler](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html) to not generate obfuscated output code (-pretty or -detailed) and then use Firebug with conditional breakpoints to check the code for errors.
3. Sometimes an exception is thrown only in production mode and not in development. You can also check that with the developer tools (firebug, java console).

Comment: Yes ,i am doing the same.Tracking down the http requests.Figured out that there was a deadlock happening on server side.